# Textview not showing inside FrameLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I have a `linearlayout` and a `textview` inside another `linearlayout`. The `linearlayout` from inside is displayed, but the problem is that the last `textview` is not. Why?

I have a `LinearLayout` and inside a `FrameLayout` and inside a `SwipeRefreshLayout` and in the middle a `TextVeiw`, but the problem is that `TextView` doesn't shows when I emulate the in the app. Why is that?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".SearchResults">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/content">


    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">



        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:text="EXAMPLE TEXT" />


    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Picture below...

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your full layout file? The layout you have put is showing the text view in my demo

Answer (score 1):

Change your xml file with this code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SearchResults">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content">


        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:text="EXAMPLE TEXT" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your frame Layout height is 0
set to match_parent

LinearLayout (main)
  SwipeRefresh...
    RelativeLayout (gravity center)
      and then your Textview

Comment: I changed it and nothing happens. Android studio says to put it back to 0dp for better performance.It also shows the search icon fab from previous Base activity... which i dont want

Comment: You can remove the Framelayout and insert linear Layout after the SwipeRefresh...I will edit the answer...

Comment: Still no change. Shall I also post my BaseActivity code?

Comment: This is your full layout xml file or there is more elements after the frame layout? Because it is missing  close </LinearLayout>

Answer (score 0):

The framelayout height is set to 0dp, kindly change that to match parent.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content">


    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="EXAMPLE TEXT" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

it helps you

Answer (score 0):

@George Patsias Change text color in textview